# Javascript object instance vs returned functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

What are the differences in creating objects in javascript between

```
test = function(a, b){
   this.calculate = function(){
      return a + b;
   }
}
obj = new test(1, 2);
console.log(obj.calculate());
```

And

```
test = function(a, b){
   return {
      calculate: function(){
         return a + b;
      }
   }
}
obj = test(1, 2);
console.log(obj.calculate());
```

I have used both in different situations but never understood the difference, I know that the latter approach has the over head of creating the functions for ever instance but still see it used in a lot of situations, can anyone clarafy this for me? I was unable to find anything about this by searching

Comment: The first one also creates the functions for every instance. The only differences is that in the first case, the new instance inherits from `test.prototype` while in the second case it directly inherits from `Object`.

Comment: This is a good read on the subject: http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/js-inheritance-by-example.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one also creates the functions for every instance. The only differences in this situation is that the new instance inherits from `test.prototype` in the first case, while  it directly inherits from `Object` in the second case.

In the first case it would be easier to let the instances share code, by adding the functions to the prototype. For example:

```
var Test = function(a, b){
   this._a = a;
   this._b = b;
};

Test.prototype.calculate = function(){
   return this._a + this._b;
};
```

Since all instances inherit from `Test.prototype`, the `calculate` function exists only once and all instances refer to the same function.

Answer (score 2):

As Felix said in the comment, the difference is the inheritance chain. The first inherits from `test.prototype` and the second from `Object`. The consequence is that if you wanted to create the function only once and make every instance share it, you'd have to do something like this:

```
test = function (a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

test.prototype.calculate = function () {
  return this.a + this.b;
}
```

Comment: :)) I was considering using the exact same notation as you. That would have been fun.